# connect to server from debian using "Connect to server" utility

Tags: debian

I'm new to debian 7.x, I'm trying to connect to server using the old utility available in Ubuntu "Connect to Server" in the menu;  can someone help me to install it in Debian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* what you are looking for is part of `nautilus`, the default Gnome file manager. Open any folder by double clicking on it (or open a terminal and run `nautilus`), then select "Connect to Server" from the file menu:

[image]

Comment: I did'nt know that it's a part of nautilus, thank you for your help